# Twitter Bootstrap Example Navbar Formatting Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am new to HTML/CSS, having watched through some tutorials on Udemy and playing around a little bit on Codecademy and Free Code Camp. Make no mistake, I am very very new, this being my first post on Stack Overflow, so please bear with me.

Right now, I have been trying to learn about the different features of Twitter Bootstrap v.4.0.0-beta, and am practicing with the navbar at the moment. I used the Youtube 'Bootstrap tutorial 2 - Installing Bootstrap the CDN way' to get me started with a framework using the Bootstrap CDN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Bootstrap the CDN way</title>
        <!--We link the CDN files here-->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>





        <!--Javascript files should be at the bottom of the page-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--JQuery file above Javascript so no errors-->

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As of now, I am trying to discover what each of the different components and subcomponents of the Twitter Bootstrap navbar examples do. I have copied and pasted the code from Bootstrap navbar section (directly under 'supported content' at the top https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler) into my framework, hoping that it would appear on my navbar, like it does on the example navbar, but instead it ended up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1a99.png). How my code reads is pictured below. My primary questions are (1) Why doesn't my code format correctly when I paste it? and (2) How can I fix some of these issues- including the font, font-size, the 3 random dots that appear, that it's all left-aligned, and the random button that appears between 'Navbar' and 'Home'. If this is too much, an answer to any of the previous questions is fine. Thanks a bunch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Bootstrap the CDN way</title>
        <!--We link the CDN files here-->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>





        <!--Javascript files should be at the bottom of the page-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--JQuery file above Javascript so no errors-->

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using code for version 4, but incuding css from 3.3.7.
Add correct css file and you should be fine:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bootstrap the CDN way</title>
  <!--We link the CDN files here-->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!--Javascript files should be at the bottom of the page-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--JQuery file above Javascript so no errors-->

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was very fast, and super helpful. Thank you.